# Euler class of vertical tangent bundle of the surface bundle over circle

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, fibre-bundles, homology, mapping-class-groups, surfaces

Suppose $\Sigma$ is an oriented genus $g>1$ surface and $h:\Sigma\to \Sigma$ is a diffeomorphism preserving a point $p$. Let $M$ be the surface bundle over $S^1$ obtained by gluing $\Sigma\times I$ via $h$ and let $\xi$ be the vertical tangent bundle over $M$, i.e. on $\Sigma\times\{t\}$ it is the tangent bundle of $\Sigma$. We know the Euler class $e(\xi)$ has evaluation $2-2g$ on $\Sigma\times\{t\}$. Can we describe the Poincaré dual of $e(\xi)$ as embedded curves? Since $h$ fixes $p$, we obtain a circle $S_p$ by gluing $\{p\}\times I$. We can calculate

$H_1(M)\cong \langle S_p\rangle\oplus H_1(\Sigma)/(h_*-\mathrm{Id})$.

Can we describe $P.D. e(\xi)$ in this presentation? Is it purely $(2-2g)[S_p]$?

Answer (score 2):

Let me not Poincare dualise, and work in cohomology.

Let me generalise the setting you have described, and consider the universal surface bundle $\pi : E \to M_g^1$ over the moduli space of surfaces with one marked point, and the section $s : M_g^1 \to E$ which selects this marked point. Let $T_\pi E \to E$ be the vertical tangent bundle, with Euler class $e \in H^2(E)$. The fibrewise Poincare dual of $s$ defines a class $\nu \in H^2(E)$ which restricts to a generator of the top cohomology of each fibre $\Sigma_g$. This gives a preferred splitting of the restriction map $i^* : H^2(E) \to H^2(\Sigma_g)$. On the other hand the map $\pi^* : H^*(M_g^1) \to H^*(E)$ has a preferred splitting given by $s^*$. As $s^* \nu = s^*e \neq 0$ these splitting are not quite compatible, but $s^*(-) - s^*(e) \cdot \pi_!(-)$ gives another splitting which annihilated $\nu$. These splittings can be used to show that the Serre spectral sequence for $\pi : E \to M_g^1$ collapses, and they give a canonical decomposition
\begin{align*}
H^2(E) &= \mathbb{Z}\{\nu\} \oplus H^1(M_g^1 ; \mathcal{H}^1(\Sigma)) \oplus H^2(M_g^1)\\
x &= \nu \cdot \pi_!(x) \oplus ? \oplus (s^*(x) - s^*(e) \cdot \pi_!(x))
\end{align*}
Under this decomposition the Euler class decomposes as
$$e = (2-2g)\nu \oplus \xi \oplus s^*(e)\cdot (1-(2-2g))$$
for a twisted cohomology class $\xi \in H^1(M_g^1 ; \mathcal{H}^1(\Sigma))$. As $M_g^1$ is an Eilenberg--Mac Lane space for the mapping class group $\Gamma_g^1$, such a twisted cohomology class is represented by a crossed homomorphism
$$\Xi : \Gamma_g^1 \longrightarrow H^1(\Sigma_g)$$
(well defined up to principal crossed homomorphisms), with respect to the natural action of $\Gamma_g^1$ on $H^1(\Sigma_g)$.

To start addressing your actual question: $\xi$ is nontrivial. It is an example of a *twisted Miller--Morita--Mumford class* as originally studied by Kawazumi and Morita. In the notation of

> N. Kawazumi, A generalization of the Morita-Mumford classes to extended mapping class groups for surfaces. Invent. Math. 131 (1998), no. 1, 137–149.

> N. Kawazumi and S. Morita, The primary approximation to the cohomology of the moduli space of curves and cocycles for the stable characteristic classes, Math. Res. Lett. 3 (1996)

it is called $m_{1,1}$ (maybe up to a sign). In the notation of

> A. Kupers, and O. Randal-Williams, On the cohomology of Torelli groups. Forum Math. Pi 8 (2020), e7

it is called $\kappa_{\epsilon e}$ (maybe up to a sign). Restricted to the Torelli subgroup $Tor_g^1 \leq \Gamma_g^1$ it gives a homomorphism
$$\Xi\vert_{Tor_g^1} : Tor_g^1 \longrightarrow H^1(\Sigma_g).$$
The rational abelianisation of $Tor_g^1$ is $\Lambda^3 H^1(\Sigma_g;\mathbb{Q})$, by a theorem of Johnson. This splits into irreducible $Sp_{2g}(\mathbb{Z})$-representations as $H^1(\Sigma_g;\mathbb{Q}) \oplus U$ and $\Xi\vert_{Tor_g^1}$ is is precisely detecting the part of the abelianisation map corresponding to the first summand. In particular the image of $\Xi$ is a full lattice inside $H^1(\Sigma_g)$. (I suspect it is $2 \cdot H^1(\Sigma_g)$, but cannot immediately remember why.)

Returning to your original question this means the following. For any $x \in H_1(\Sigma_g)$ there is a $N \neq 0$ and a pointed diffeomorphism $h : \Sigma_g \to \Sigma_g$, which may be taken to be in the Torelli group, such that
$$PD(e) = (2-2g)[S_p] + [N \cdot x] \in H_1(M) = \mathbb{Z}\{[S_p]\} \oplus H_1(\Sigma_g)/(h_* - Id).$$

Comment: Thanks for clear explanations. Can we further control N? The case I'm interested is when N is a multiple of 2-2g, which makes PD(e) similar to the one on the product bundle.